# Reference a nodeset without copying it

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

Deep inside a stylesheet, I have some logic that looks sort of like this:

```
<xsl:variable name="v1">
    <!-- define structure within v1 -->
</variable>
<xsl:variable name="v2">
    <!-- define structure within v2 -->
</variable>
<xsl:variable name="valuesMap" select="exsl:node-set($v1)"/>
<xsl:variable name="valuesMap_2" select="exsl:node-set($v2)"/>
...
<xsl:variable name="tmp">
    <xsl:choose>        
        <xsl:when test="$isSomeCondition">
            <xsl:copy-of select="$valuesMap"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:copy-of select="$valuesMap_2"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
     </xsl:choose>
 </xsl:variable>
 <xsl:variable name="valueSet" select="exsl:node-set($tmp)"/>
 <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="not($valueSet/Child[@someAttribute=$someOtherVariable])">
       ...
    </xsl:when>
    ...
```

The variables `$valuesMap` and `$valuesMap_2` are variables that contain node sets. They are defined elsewhere and are referenced several places in this transformation.

What I am trying to do is check a condition (`$isSomeCondition`) and then set a local variable, `$valueSet`, to refer to either `$valuesMap` or `$valuesMap_2`. I'm doing this because there are several places in this template where I need to choose between `$valuesMap` or `$valuesMap_2` and I'd rather just make the decision once and use a local variable to keep track of it.

The code above works, but I'm concerned about using `copy-of`: I fear it will completely duplicate the contents of `$valuesMap` or `$valuesMap_2`, and that could be a problem because these variables could contain some rather large structures and this specific template will be used numerous times per transformation.

I've already tried using `value-of` but that seems to capture the *text* content of the variables, not the XML structure.

Is there any way to reference the correct structure without having to copy it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Combine the two variables into one, e.g.

```
<xsl:variable name="vMapRTF">
  <v1>
    <!-- define structure within v1 -->
  </v1>
  <v2>
    <!-- define structure within v2 -->
  </v2>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:variable name="vMap" select="exsl:node-set($vMapRTF)" />

<xsl:variable name="valueSet" select="$vMap/*[2 - $isSomeCondition]" />
```

Here I'm taking advantage of the fact that a boolean expression in a numeric context is treated as `0` if it's false and `1` if it's true, so if `$isSomeCondition` is true it'll pick `$vMap/*[1]` (the `v1` element) and if it's false it'll pick `$vMap/*[2]`.

If you still need the separate `$valuesMap` and `$valuesMap_2` variables for use elsewhere in the transformation then just declare them as e.g.

```
<xsl:variable name="valuesMap" select="$vMap/v1" />
```

Comment: I posted an alternate solution using exslt:dynamic. Not sure it's actually better, but it is interesting...

Answer (score 0):

I found an alternate solution using the "evaluate" function in then ["dynamic" package of EXSLT](http://www.exslt.org/dyn/):

```
<xsl:variable name="tmpName">
    <xsl:choose>        
        <xsl:when test="$isSomeCondition">
            <xsl:text>$valuesMap</xsl:text>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:text>$valuesMap_2</xsl:text>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="valueSet" select="dyn:evaluate($tmpName)"/>
 <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="not($valueSet/Child[@someAttribute=$someOtherVariable])">
       ...
    </xsl:when>
    ...
```

On the other hand, this uses an `eval` function... I'd guess that Ian's still performs better than this, ...and I'd guess that this solution *probably* performs better than my original problem which used `copy-of`.